# ratio calculation and sort the calculated rates

Tags: r

```
  df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
 timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

 df8 <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hirenvadher954/Worldometers- 
  Scraping/master/countries.csv',
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 install.packages("tidyverse")
 library(tidyverse)

   df %>% 
   left_join(df8, by = c("countryName" = "country_name")) %>% 
 mutate(population = as.numeric(str_remove_all(population, ","))) %>% 
  group_by(countryName) %>% 
    group_by(countryName) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
summarize(population = sum(population, na.rm = TRUE),
        confirmed = sum(confirmed, na.rm = TRUE),
        recovered = sum(recovered, na.rm = TRUE),
        death = sum(death, na.rm = TRUE),
        death_prop = paste0(as.character(death), "/", as.character(population))
        )
```

in this code

population / death  rate was calculated.

highest population / death have rate

Finding 10 countries.

**confirmed and recovered**

**dont will be available.**

`10 x 6
   countryName         population confirmed recovered death death_prop

   <chr>                    <dbl>     <int>     <int> <int> <chr>

 1 Afghanistan         4749258212    141652     16505  3796 3796/4749258212 
 2 Albania              351091234     37233     22518  1501 1501/351091234

 3 Algeria             5349827368    206413     88323 20812 20812/5349827368
 4 Andorra                9411324     38518     18054  2015 2015/9411324

 5 Angola              4009685184      1620       435   115 115/4009685184

 6 Anguilla               1814018       161        92     0 0/1814018

 7 Antigua and Barbuda   11947338      1230       514   128 128/11947338

 8 Argentina           5513884428    232975     66155 10740 10740/5513884428
 9 Armenia              361515646    121702     46955  1626 1626/361515646

10 Aruba                 13025452      5194      3135    91 91/13025452`

data is an example.

the information is not correct.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have edited sir. @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is in cumulative format meaning all the values for today have all the values till yesterday. So take only `max` values of each column and calculate `death_prop`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(df8, by = c("countryName" = "country_name")) %>% 
  mutate(population = as.numeric(str_remove_all(population, ","))) %>%
  group_by(countryName) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(population:death), max, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(death_prop = death/population * 100) %>%
  arrange(desc(death_prop))


# A tibble: 215 x 5
#   countryName    population  year death death_prop
#   <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <dbl>
# 1 San Marino          33860  2019    42     0.124 
# 2 Belgium          11589623  2020  9312     0.0803
# 3 Andorra             77142  2019    51     0.0661
# 4 Spain            46754778  2020 28752     0.0615
# 5 Italy            60461826  2020 32877     0.0544
# 6 United Kingdom   67886011  2020 36914     0.0544
# 7 France           65273511  2020 28432     0.0436
# 8 Sweden           10099265  2020  4029     0.0399
# 9 Sint Maarten        42388  2019    15     0.0354
#10 Netherlands      17134872  2020  5830     0.0340
# … with 205 more rows
```